# Baguazhang in India?

Tags: bagua

I'm a girl, age 14, intent on learning Bagua, an ancient internal Taoist martial art which originates from China. Funny that I got inspired to this from a game (cough*tekken 3*cough), but I think that I'm allowed to be a fan girl...he he...

I'm quite flexible...my fingers unnecessarily more so (my left pinky can touch the back of my left hand with 2 degree angle in between), and I have a fairly good experience in Chinese Boxing.

I have been trying to learn Bagua by online sources (YouTube videos by "Clear's Internal Arts") but I doubt that it'll be enough when I don't even have an instructor. My family is about to be transferred to Delhi, so I have been looking for an instructor there online, but haven't been able to come up with anything. I just found this site today, so...can anyone please help me find one? Or more than one?

Comment: I feel you. Xiao Yu's cute and cool. xD Google didn't help me find an instructor based in Dehli. Try looking for posters and flyers when you are already there. Some people here might also recommend someone to you if we wait.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised.

Comment: Uh...I realised it now...it may be. I just need some help, that's all. Please don't. I don't have much to find my answer...

Comment: Imagine yourself in my place, Sardathiron. Its so frustrating!

Comment: I absolutely get it. However, this site rules are there for a reason. It is therefore not the best place to ask this question. You might have more luck in either rephrasing your question in more general terms ("How can I go finding a X dojo?" although that might be too broad) or looking elsewhere. Alternatively, [learn how to use Google](https://search.disconnect.me/searchTerms/serp?search=65705b80-4d64-406f-8c3d-732bfa023450)...

Comment: Uh...then can you gimme the link to the site rules? Cause I truly, really, literally and not sarcastically never knew that localised questions weren't allowed in this site. So...can you?

Comment: And...the network here is too unsupporting to allow usage of Google Maps. I actually work with Kbps on a regular day, and right now its winter monsoon here.

Comment: The [tour](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help centre](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help) are on the "help" menu at the top right of the page. On the [on-topic](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, the first questions that should not be asked on Martial Arts is *recommendations for schools or teachers in area X (too localized)*. Sorry to hear about your network connectivity, that does suck.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Delhi myself. Since you are a 14 year old girl, I don't imagine you'll have a lot of choice of gyms or martial arts, since you'll have to devote time to school etc. and you probably don't have too many options when it comes to transport either. That said Delhi has its share of Taekwondo and Karate academies, how about picking up one of those ? Instead of an obscure martial art..

Comment: I was also looking for other martial arts. I think thatTaeKwonDo may be a good choice, but I believe that focuses on the leg-power more, and my feet don't seem to be so special. And I'm not interested in Karate, I dunno why though...

Comment: Plus...I think that I'm progressing pretty good from those online vids...

Comment: I learnt taekwondo for 6 years, I am a bit partial to it. Don't look for speciality in your body, develop your specialities :). Try to find a good ITF school, it has a very active community with lots of tournaments in Delhi. Attend a sparring session and belt promotion test before deciding, these will give you a good idea of what the school/club is like. Give me further details of your location, and I will be able to assist you further.